# Automating the Tree Traversal in C#

Tags: c#, recursive-query, mptt

Good day pals! Currently I'm studying this database model design called Modified Pre-order Tree Traversal (MPTT). After seeing the drawbacks of using Common Table Expressions (CTE) because of its poor quality performance, I found recommendations of using MPTT. But before I can use the benefit of MPTT, I need to redesign my database table by adding 'right' and 'left' node values. To do that I need to make a program that will automate and update the values of the each data in the table. My problem is I can't make a program that will automate the node values. I'm trying to convert a php language to a C# code, but I couldn't make it. One of my weakness in programming is creating 'recursive' methods.

I'm using this link as my reference.
[Hierarchical database model](http://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database-3/)

And here's the code I'm trying to convert to C#

```
<?php 
function rebuild_tree($parent, $left) {   
    // the right value of this node is the left value + 1   
    $right = $left+1;   

    // get all children of this node   
    $result = mysql_query('SELECT title FROM tree '.   
                           'WHERE parent="'.$parent.'";');  
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {   
        // recursive execution of this function for each   
        // child of this node   
        // $right is the current right value, which is   
        // incremented by the rebuild_tree function   
        $right = rebuild_tree($row['title'], $right);   
    }   

    // we've got the left value, and now that we've processed
    // the children of this node we also know the right value   
    mysql_query('UPDATE tree SET lft='.$left.', rgt='.   
                 $right.' WHERE title="'.$parent.'";');   

    // return the right value of this node + 1   
    return $right+1;   
}   
?>
```

Comment: What is your specific issue? C# and PHP are generally quite similar and your code is no exception. The conversion of this code should be quite straightforward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my own code, please let me know if there is a much better solution

```
    int right = 0;

    public int rebuild_tree(int parent, int left)
    {
        // the right value of this node is the left value + 1
        right = left + 1;

        // get all children of this node
        command = conn.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = "SELECT cat_id FROM tbl_RefDataCategory_mst WHERE parent_id=@parent";
        command.Parameters.Add("parent", SqlDbType.Int).Value = parent;

        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                int temp = Convert.ToInt32(reader["cat_id"]);
                right = rebuild_tree(temp, right);
            }

            command = conn.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = "UPDATE tbl_RefDataCategory_mst SET lft=@l, rgt=@r WHERE cat_id=@p";
            command.Parameters.Add("l", SqlDbType.Int).Value = left;
            command.Parameters.Add("r", SqlDbType.Int).Value = right;
            command.Parameters.Add("p", SqlDbType.Int).Value = parent;

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        return right + 1;
    }
```